# iPad 2 won't keep 'remember me' cookie on a website

Tags: safari, ipad, ios

I'm running an iPad 2 on iOS7.

I have 3 iPad 2 and an iPad mini. All running iOS7. On all of the devices, I access a site which has a 'remember me' cookie to save me having to log in again. This works fine on all devices except for one iPad 2. I have gone through all the safari settings and they match the other devices. I'm stuck now. What is the problem? It happened on iOS6 as well. The cookie appears to get deleted when I turn the ipad off and then back on.

I cleared the cookies and data in case that was the problem, but it still doesn't remember on this device.

[image: safari security settings]

Comment: Is the time and date correct on the iPad 2?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure safari is not running in "private" mode.  Open Safari, tap on the multiple tabs icon (should be furthest to right), and make sure private is not highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check that your unknown web server, let's name it `X web server` for clarity, didn't put in place a security function to avoid your account to be stolen along the following scheme:

1. `X web server` stores who and from which software, OS and location `john` is connecting from within a session cookie.
2. If `john` connects with the same identification as the last presented one
   his access is granted.
3. If `john` connects with a new identification, and `john` isn't connected elsewhere, then his access is granted and his cookie updated, else
   if `john` is already connected with another identification, then this is an
   attempt to steal `john` identification and this access is denied, and the
   used cookie (presumably stolen) is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem on my iPad....  Go to the passwords and auto fill option...  (2nd line down in your screen shot above) and select remember passwords and the auto fill option.